# add handler for subreports with rdlc reports vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a main report with 2 subreports (trying to include 2). Currently what I have is this...

- On button click I query data and populate Main Report -Report1
- Once this data is populated I added a AddHandler to populate data for 1st subreport - this works GREAT!
  -Now I'm trying to query data for 2nd Subreport the same way but it's not showing my any of the data...

CODE:
        'Querying data and other code not included...

```
    Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables("DataTable2"))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)

AddHandler ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf Me.SubreportProcessingEventHandler


 Public Sub SubreportProcessingEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)
    Dim adapter1 As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String = ""
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim objConnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection

    objConnection = New SqlConnection(conn)
    objConnection.Open()
```

Finally select data for first subreport. here it shows data correctly!

```
    SQL="SELECT A,B from tblA"
    adapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    adapter1.Fill(ds, "DataTable3")
    e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables("DataTable3")))
```

Now I'm doing the same for subreport 2! but data doesn't get through!

```
    SQL ="SELECT C,D from tblB"
    adapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    adapter1.Fill(ds, "DataTable4")
    e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables("DataTable4")))

End sub
```

I have created DataTable4 for subreport 2 with the exact fields. I'm basically doing tthe same exact thing for both subreports.

Do i need multiple handlers? what am i Doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: iirc parameters are passed in the eventargs that allow you to determine what's required by the call ie which subreport is calling for its data. But, looking at the code you've given (though I appreciate it's simplified) it doesn't look as though you need subreports at all - just multiple data sources.  I mean, normally a parameter is passed in the 'e' which effectively acts as a WHERE clause so that the subreport is showing related child data to the data in the parent report, whereas you seem to be pulling unrelated data.

Comment: @peterg - I need to query data - I'm actually doing a lot of Left Joins since I save a lot of the my values as ID's - so when displaying it i need to left join my reference table to display Text

Comment: @peterG - now it is related data - it's all for the same CLIENTID. This field appears in all my tables. I just don't know how to get this to work. It's my first time working with .rdlc reports. I found this to work for one of my reports so im continuing to do it for all. I'm more of a Ms. Access user

Comment: The usual pitfall with reports is that the name ("DataSet1") doesn't _exactly_ match the one specified at designtime. Also I found this link helpful: http://www.gotreportviewer.com/subreports/index.html

Comment: If it's all for the same CLIENTID it sounds a bit like you just need to use a join query to populate the main part of the report. Um, maybe I'm not too clear on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @Bobski show the datasource of the report. "DataSet1" should not be the same each time, you're just overwriting that source

Comment: @peterG - i have Report1 (main report) - where I display client name, address, etc. Now for Report2 (subreport) - i display other related info to that client (evaluation, appointments) and Report3( 2nd subreport) I'm doing the same thing showing additional information all for that same client. Each one of the querries is long because i do up to 6 joins to get the text values (since I save them as ID's). So while I can use a filter, i'm okay doing it this way as long as my data gets displayed in all the subreports.

Comment: @Jaxedin - at the end of the AddHandler - if i check the values of each datatable - it's showing me the correct values. I fill a different DataTable for each query that I write. the values are there just not getting passed to report. It's my first time working with rdlc reports. Any help on improving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Bobski You're using DataSet1 as the name for every source. Is that OK?  On the second select you're overwriting the tblA result. Also, use a new Dataset for the tlbB query.

Comment: Right - so if I understand correctly, what you have is three queries which each have the ClientID as the defining WHERE clause. So actually, you don't need subreports, just three tablix, three datasources, three queries.

Comment: @peterG - you are correct! so should I simply create three strongly defined datasets with DataTable in each one and fill those datatables with my data? please see image in question. I'm just not sure how to do this properly! I was trying to simply fill all my datatables within the DataSet1 and go off those to do my report

Comment: Yes, that will work. Give them different names (in fact I think you won't be able to avoid this) Then add all three using the same code you used to add just one in your orig code. The reportdatasources bind just based on field names matching - nothing exotic. (So you can even use a dataset at designtime and a list of objects at runtime, as long as the names match up)

Comment: @peterG - but in this case I will have to use many DataSets - basically I was hoping to go off one DataSet as long as I Have different DataTables within that DataSet. Wouldn't I be able to add different dataTables as my datasets and go off those? I'm trying to make this as clean as possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right, one dataset with a datatable corresponding to each query, then bind each reportdatasource to its appropriate table. As I said, the key is that the names all match up - specifically, although you are working in VB it's still case-sensitive. (as the same reports etc have to work with C# etc too)

Comment: @peterG - but that's what Im doing! :) but when I do e.DataSource for my DataTable4 - while the data is show in the datatable ( i see it using data visualizer) it does not show up on the report! I'm going nuts here

Comment: OK if you are using three separate datasources then you don't need to use the eventhandler and adding the datasource to the 'e'. However, I suspect that there is something else we are missing here - maybe a typo. If the data is in DataTable4 then there is a problem in the binding. The RDS acts as a bridge between the report and the data; the names must match up at each step.
Also bear in mind there are several ways to tackle this - have a look at that link in my previous.

Comment: @peterG - in the case that I'm doing with my EventHandler as it currently is shown in my question - am i able to add the DataSource as my DataTable4 - or should I do it differently. My dilemna is if I want to add DataTable5 am i going to be able to do that. What's happening is my subreport has some textvalues and next to them I'm to display data - i see the heading but no data next to it. But I see data in dataTable4 Basically I'm not sure if my eventHandler can handle multiple queries and DataTables

Comment: After a bit of thought I suspect you are still making this more complex than it needs to be. Have a look at that link, in particular "Option #2: using nested data regions" . The key thing happening there is the use of 'First' on the master end of the master-details data.

Comment: @peterG - you were correct peter. I'm using three seperate source - no subreports and everything is looking great. Thanks! If you want to post this as your answer i'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code you've given, you don't need subreports at all. The simplest (if not necessarily most efficient) way to tackle this is to use three separate queries, with corresponding DataTables and ReportDataSources.
More generally, situations that at first sight might seem to call for subreports can in fact be solved by other means, such as grouping and/or using a query with one or more joins. For instance, the canonical Order plus OrderLines report can be constructed using a join query in conjunction with textboxes holding the FIRST keyword against Order info, and a Tablix displaying the order lines.
Also I found this link helpful: [http://www.gotreportviewer.com/subreports/index.html](http://Also%20I%20found%20this%20link%20helpful:http://www.gotreportviewer.com/subreports/index.html)